# How to move a LinearLayout to the right side of the toolbar

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add into the toolbar a `TextView` and a `Spinner` to implement language change from there. The problem it's that I added a `LinearLayout` to the `toolbar` but I cannot manage to move it to the right side so it won't get over the title of the activity, or to stay next to it.

Right now the `LinearLayout` is set like that (+ where i want it to be):

[image]

.xml code:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/limba"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <Spinner
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_limba"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And the result it is :

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like :

[image]

I achieved that by setting a `android:paddingLeft` but that wont work on all the devices the same way, so I am looking for another solution.

I have tried adding `gravity` but it wasn't moving my layout.

Answer (score 3):

add  **android:layout_gravity="right"** in Linear layout.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I have tried with `gravity` for the `layout` and probably 
 by mistake `layout_gravity` on the `views`. It is working now!

Comment: lol I didn't have the orientation set thats why gravity wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout and provide

> android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

property to LinearLayout.

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_limba"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```